# How can I authenticate a npm registry with azure devops build pipeline?

Tags: authentication, npm, azure-devops

I have an app I'm creating a build pipeline for in Azure DevOps. It uses npm packages which are in a private npm registry (with code created from a different Azure DevOps organisation). When I run `npm ci` (or `npm install`) it fails with the following error:

> npm ERR! code E401
>
> npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/b2d01466-6e2c-4b55-8b90-e3ed41afca4a, Basic realm="https://pkgsproduks1.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated

The specific packages which fail are the ones from the other organisation, which return a `401` when trying to get them.

I thought the best practice to authenticate this was to create a Service Connection within Azure DevOps. I've created a Personal Access Token within the organisation which hosts the npm packages, and used it to create a Service Connection in the organisation which contains my build pipeline. I then included it in my build pipeline yaml as follows:

```yaml
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: Install npm packages
  inputs:
    command: 'ci'
    workingDir: 'Path/To/Working/Directory'
    customEndpoint: 'Custom npm registry'
```

I've also tried using the `npm authenticate` build step before this (both with and without the `customEndpoint: 'Custom npm registry'` in the install step) and while the `npm authenticate` runs successfully it doesn't make any difference to the error I'm getting. I've also tried setting up the Service Connection to use my username and password rather than a PAT, but that made no difference either.

The `.npmrc` within my project is as follows (modified slightly):

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@{scope}:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_packaging/{feedName}/npm/registry/
@{scope}:always-auth=true
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with the authentication, or link to an article giving an example of doing this across multiple Azure DevOps organisations?

Comment: Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops#restore-and-publish-npm-packages-outside-your-organization

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: Thanks for following up. I needed to move on to other things so I temporarily removed the dependency on the other registry, but I'll come back to your answer when I need to look at this again.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of months as well. I've added the external feed as a service using PAT authentication, but nothing is working. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/7621

Comment: trying to get this working for a week now. so far I can make it publish a single library using `publishRegistry: useFeed` + `publishFeed: 'some-uuid-and-not-the-name`. But our use case is more complex and I would need to run the `npm publish` from within a script. there it keeps saying *code E401* any help is really appriciated.

Comment: Any update on this yet?

Answer (score 3):

I just killed a few hours troubleshooting a similar NPM authentication issue with a hosted build agent for Azure DevOps.

I did have the `NPM Authenticate` job in the pipline, and I was still experiencing this error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login
```

As it turned, the project had a mixture of `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<myorg>/_packaging` and `https://<myorg>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging` (the legacy URL for the same NPM registry) in scattered `.npmrc` files.

Making them all to consistently use `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<myorg>/_packaging` had solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `.npmrc` should look like:

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_packaging/{feed}/npm/registry/
@{scope}:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{otherorganization}/_packaging/{feed}/npm/registry/
@{otherscope}:registry=https://{thirdPartyRepository}/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
```

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood this, it didn't make any difference. I now have `@{scope}:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{otherorganisation}/_packaging/{feed}/npm/registry/
always-auth=true` but still get the same error.